# mean of $x$ for all $x<0$ in standard normal

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

How do you estimate the expected mean of $x$ for all observations where $x<0$ and $x$ is distributed standard normal.

Comment: With an integral, noting that  $e^{-x^2/2}$ has derivative $-x \,e^{-x^2/2}$

Comment: See Wikipedia (& maybe other refs) on 'half normal distribution' or 'folded normal distribution`: $-\sqrt{2/\pi}.$